# Cumulative Percentage Categorization Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've got a query that's been driving me up the wall. The t-sql query is as follows but with about a thousand records in the source table, it's taking forever and a day to run.  Is there any faster way of accomplishing the same task anyone might think of:

```
SELECT *, ROUND((SELECT SUM(PartTotal) 
FROM PartSalesRankings 
WHERE Item_Rank <= sub.Item_Rank) /
 (SELECT SUM(PartTotal) 
  FROM PartSalesRankings) * 100, 2) as Cum_PC_Of_Total 
FROM PartSalesRankings As sub
```

I'm trying to classify my inventory into A,B, and C categories based on percentage of cost, but it needs to be a cumulative percentage of cost, ie. 'A' parts make up 80% of my cost, 'B' parts make up the next 15%, and 'C' parts are the last 5%.  There's obviously more to the sql statement than what I included, but the code I posted is the bottle-neck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Aj

Comment: Probably example data and results would help

Comment: Sorry you're correct, in case anyone else happens along this post, the results are simply a part number, it's total sales for a period, and an auto-number column ordered from greatest sales to lowest sales. (the actual part numbers and dollar values aren't particularly relevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in response, but I've been up to my neck in other stuff, but after a great deal of trial and error I've found the following to be the fastest method:

```
Select companypartnumber
     , (PartTotal + IsNull(Cum_Lower_Ranks, 0) ) / Sum(PartTotal) over() * 100 as Cum_PC_Of_Total
    from PartSalesRankings PSRMain
   Left join 
        (
            Select PSRTop.Item_Rank, Sum(PSRBelow.PartTotal) as Cum_Lower_Ranks
              from partSalesRankings PSRTop
              Left join PartSalesRankings PSRBelow on PSRBelow.Item_Rank < PSRTop.Item_Rank
             Group by PSRTop.Item_Rank 
        ) as PSRLowerCums on PSRLowerCums.Item_Rank = PSRMain.Item_Rank
) sub2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH SumPartTotal AS
(SELECT SUM(PartTotal) as SumPartTotal, Item_Rank
FROM PartSalesRankings 
GROUP BY Item_Rank
),
CumSumPartTotal AS
(SELECT SUM(Sub.SumPartTotal) as CumSumPartTotal, SPT.Item_Rank
FROM SumPartTotal as SPT
  INNER JOIN SumPartTotal as Sub ON
    SPT.Item_Rank >= Sub.Item_Rank
GROUP BY SPT.Item_Rank
),
SumTotal AS
(SELECT SUM(PartTotal) as SumTotal
FROM PartSalesRankings
)
SELECT *,
  ROUND((CumSumPartTotal.CumSumPartTotal * 100.0) / SumTotal.SumTotal, 2)  as Cum_PC_Of_Total 
FROM PartSalesRankings As sub
  INNER JOIN CumSumPartTotal ON
    sub.Item_Rank = CumSumPartTotal.Item_Rank
  INNER JOIN SumTotal ON
    sub.Item_Rank = SumTotal.Item_Rank
```

It should give your query a speed boost.